# add buttons to table arrangement dynamically in WPF

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I would like to make a 2-columns table arrangement and to add buttons to the table at runtime.

what I did is defining nested StackPanels similar to this.

```
        <StackPanel MinWidth="500" MaxWidth="800" MaxHeight="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="20">Some Title</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Content="" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Margin="10,0,0,10"></Button>
                <Button Content="" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Margin="10,0,0,10"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Is this a correct starting, or there is a better and easier arrangement?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a model-view implementation with ListView and bind it to a collection of items which have the respective handler for the button:

WPF:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MyItems}>
     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding={Binding Name}></GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Button">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                              <Button Command={Binding ButtonPress}>Click me</Button>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

You can also set the ItemsSource inside the .cs file for your view as well, otherwise use a ViewModel class to handle your view and create a `ObservableCollection<MyItemWrapper>` property which will hold all the table items.

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItemWrapper> _myItems;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItemWrapper>();
        //// add your initial items
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItemWrapper> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponents()
    }
}
```

MyItem and MyItemWrapper

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemWrapper
{
    private MyItem _item;
    public MyItemWrapper(MyItem item)
    {
        _item = item;
        ButtonPress = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnButtonPress);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _item.Name; }
    }

    public DelegateCommand<object> ButtonPress { get; private set; }

    private void OnButtonPress(object args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button pressed for: " + Name);
    }
}
```

This will ultimately be able to add/remove items at runtime by using MyItems inside the view model and have your list view always update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using WrapPanel, and I will share what I have did, Thanks for Vlad for binding part:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CartItemC.CartItems}" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanel" MaxWidth="300" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel MaxWidth="300">
                <Button Command="{Binding ButtonPress}">Click me</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you want it dynamically, well you don't want to use `StackPanel` as you would end up maintaining the `width` and `height` of the controls inside it. Given you want the controls to automatically resize its own size.

The best solution is to use `Grid` if you really want to make a 2 column table arrangement.

Take a look at this [example](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html).

Sample code

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```